# How to plot horizontal lines for high and low of all weekly candles to be used on 1m and 5m charts

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How to plot horizontal lines for all the weekly high and lows, to be used on lower timeframes.

I've been trying to code this for awhile now and cant seem to get all weekly high and lows plotted just 1 pair of them, the first pic is weekly chart and how it looks, second pic is 1m chart.

can anyone help would love to figure this out and have as indicator, thanks
[weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlFwh.png)

[1m chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dECzK.png)

if someone could help me out with this problem I would be very greatful, thank you